# How do I convert a human-readable date + time to a Unix timestamp in Python?

Tags: python, time, timestamp, data-conversion

I have a bunch of human-readable dates and times (to be specific, the default format in nginx logs) that I wish to convert to Unix timestamps. The format is like this:

```
04/Dec/2013:18:56:05 +0000
```

What's the most reliable way of doing this? Are there any libraries I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

From the doc link

> The datetime.strptime() class method creates a datetime object from a string representing a date and time and a corresponding format string.

Call it like

```
datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
```

Comment: Figuring out the format string to use is left as a exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks, worked great! The format is as follows, for anyone else looking for it: `%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z`